# How to drawing bezier curve with animation in Android using cubicTo?

Tags: android, canvas, android-animation, android-drawable, bezier

I've been searching for simple example and solution in stackoverflow, but I couldn't find one. So, I'll ask a new one and my apologies if this question have been asked before.

First, I want to make an apps that draw a Japanese Kanji Stroke using bezier curve, I already have 1 starting point, with 3 curves, for example :

M(11,54.25)

c(3.19,0.62) (6.25,0.75) (9.73,0.5)

c(20.64,-1.5) (50.39,-5.12) (68.58,-5.24)

c(3.6,-0.02) (5.77,0.24) (7.57,0.49)

What I have been found during searching in internet is, it looks like I could use Path.cubicTo() and use canvas as to draw it (using canvas.drawPath()). 
And also, I want the canvas to draw it using animation at given frame rate or speed.

Anyone could give me a simple example or maybe some clue or anything that I can work with ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can find great example here:

http://www.jayway.com/2012/08/29/creating-custom-android-views-part-3-animating-your-custom-views-smoothly/

The sources are also there so it's very easy.

Your approach is good- you basically use Path.cubicTo in your View's onDraw and invalidate views while changing input coordinates. You can do it in another thread or create ValueAnimator and invalidate view in AnimatorUpdateListener.

Comment: Wow, thanks man, really appreciate it. I hope I could up vote your answer, but unfortunately I can't because lack of reputation. Okay, I'll check on the example first.

Comment: @GabrielJuan you can accept it as correct answer instead if its correct